# StencilJS Notification Component

Tags: stenciljs

I'm trying to build a notification toast component. The idea is to have a parent component `notification`, which is used for

- positioning on the viewport, and
- to spawn `notification-instance` child components using a `push` method on the consumer of the `notification` component.

`notification-instance` is the actual notification toast. It is responsible for

- dismissing itself after set duration, and
- handling click events.

When the initial call to `push` is executed, an instance of `notification-instance` is shown on the viewport. My issue is that any consecutive calls to `push` (e.g. after 3 seconds) doesn't do anything. However, the `render` function within `notification` is run.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong or missing?

`notification` component

```js
@State()
private notificationInstance;

@Method()
public push(message: string, type: NotificationType = NotificationType.None, options?: NotificationOptions): void {
    this.notificationInstance = this.createNotificationInstance(message, type, options);
}

render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <Host class={this.position}>
            { this.notificationInstance }
        </Host>
    );
}

createNotificationInstance(message: string, type: NotificationType, {dismissAfterDuration, dismissOnClick, showProgressBar, pauseOnFocusLoss, pauseOnHover}: NotificationOptions): JSX.Element {
    return <mi-notification-instance
        message={message}
        notificationType={type}
        dismissAfterDuration={dismissAfterDuration}
        dismissOnClick={dismissOnClick}
        showProgressBar={showProgressBar}
        pauseOnFocusLoss={pauseOnFocusLoss}
        pauseOnHover={pauseOnHover}>
    </mi-notification-instance>;
}
```

`notification-instance`

```js
@Listen('click', { capture: true })
handleClick(): void {
    if (this.dismissOnClick) {
        this.dismiss();
    }
}

render(): JSX.Element {
    const miNotificationInstanceMarkup = (
        <Host>
            <div class="notification progress">
                {this.notificationType && this.notificationType !== 'none' ? this.renderIcon(this.notificationType) : null}
                <p class="notification__message">{ this.message }</p>
            </div>
        </Host>
    );

    return miNotificationInstanceMarkup;
}

dismiss(): void {
    this.hostElement.remove();
}
```